# Been doing frontend for 2 years now and still unsure when/how to use classes

Tags: javascript

In my day to day job, I deal with a backend built on Ruby and the frontend is React and vanilla Javascript.  I understand how React is essentially built on classes but I don't understand, based on the simple examples given, that it isn't backend.

Like:

```
class Person() {
    constructor(firstName, lastName) {
      this.firstName = firstName;
      this.lastName = lastName;
    }
 }

 let person = new Person("robert", "smith")
```

^ Isn't the above code essentially what my Ruby backend would be doing when a user enters data in a field -- it would take that data, and create a `Person` based on the Ruby model and store it in the database?

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. This isn't an ORM so it's not storing anything in the database.

Comment: Well that piece of code is run on the client, and not the server.

Comment: @Keith right, but what purpose does it serve?  Why would you need a collection of Person objects created solely on the client?  -- or rather, what purpose CAN it serve?  I guess I just can't picture how it can be used

Comment: You can do stuff with it client side, this comes with advantages, like less server load, a more responsive UI etc, back end updates could then be handled with Ajax/websockets etc.

Answer (score 0):

The front end has so much more to offer than just basic representation of data

1. actual [html5 canvas games](https://www.creativebloq.com/html5/top-20-html5-games-1122788), not java just pure secure neat
   JavaScript
2. dumb that down, the html5 canvas can be used to create images, and beautiful representation of art, audio, and various other things, look at [these](https://p5js.org/examples/)
3. JavaScript based music creation apps, video editing apps, basically services that require processing power that is quite huge, and is likely to DDOS a server if too many users are present,

all these thing require OOP

why do this in JS instead of CPP?, well cause JS is more fun to write that CPP, and definitely more manageable